# I've installed pyinstaller, but it won't run

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Trying to use pyinstaller and I had "Successfully installed pyinstaller-3.0 pypiwin32-223 pywin32-224" according to Command prompt.

however, when I tried to run with `$pyinstaller`, I receive this message

> File "C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 1
>   SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe3' in file C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Your name is problem: https://www.codetable.net/hex/e3

Comment: I don't understand why, can you explain?

Comment: if `João Pedro` was `Joao Pedro` then there would not be any problem

Comment: So you are saying that pyinstaller won't execute because my user name has a latin character?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue while reading the path for pyinstaller because of the presence of that Lattin character. Either you can convert it to `utf8` format or change it. It will resolve the issue.